# Understanding Tensorflow LSTM models?

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, tensorflow

I have some trouble understanding LSTM models in [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/).
For simplicity, let us consider the [Example program](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/examples/nlp/lstm.py).

I use the [tflearn](http://tflearn.org/) as a wrapper as it does all the initialization and other higher level stuff automatically.

Till line number `42` `net = tflearn.input_data([None, 200])` it's pretty clear what happens.

You load a dataset into variables and make it of standard lengths in this case 200. for both the input variables and also the 2 classes present in this case are converted to one hot vectors.

What I would like to know here is how the LSTM takes the input and across how many samples does it predict the output?

What do these parameters indicate: `n_words=20000` & `net = tflearn.embedding(net, input_dim=20000, output_dim=128)`?

My goal is to [replicate](http://jeffdonahue.com/lrcn/) the [activity recognition dataset in the paper.](http://arxiv.org/abs/1411.4389)

For example, I would like to input a 4096 vector as input to the lstm and the idea is to take 16 of such vectors and then produce the classification result.

I think the code would look like this but I don't know how the input to the LSTM should be given

```
from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import

import tflearn
from tflearn.data_utils import to_categorical, pad_sequences
from tflearn.datasets import imdb

train, val = something.load_data()
trainX, trainY = train #each X sample is a (16,4096) nd float64 
valX, valY = val #each Y is a one hot vector of 101 classes.

net = tflearn.input_data([None, 16,4096])
net = tflearn.embedding(net, input_dim=4096, output_dim=256)
net = tflearn.lstm(net, 256)
net = tflearn.dropout(net, 0.5)
net = tflearn.lstm(net, 256)
net = tflearn.dropout(net, 0.5)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 101, activation='softmax')
net = tflearn.regression(net, optimizer='adam',
                         loss='categorical_crossentropy')

model = tflearn.DNN(net, clip_gradients=0., tensorboard_verbose=3)
model.fit(trainX, trainY, validation_set=(testX, testY), show_metric=True,
          batch_size=128,n_epoch=2,snapshot_epoch=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Arsenal,

We have to reshape the input data to fit in the LSTM's input layer like:

```
   trainX= np.reshape(trainX, (-1, 16, 4096))
   testX = np.reshape(testX, (-1, 16, 4096))
```

When one layer's output goes to the following layer's input, the earlier layer must produce a sequence like:

```
    net = tflearn.lstm(net,128, dropout=0.2, return_seq=True)
    net = tflearn.lstm(net,128)
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, num_classes, activation='softmax')
```

Hope this helps.